# set date format in Gson in jsp

Tags: java, json, gson, date-format

I'm using Gson to convert Json to an object in Java. Json that i'm trying to convert has quite complicated structure.

```
{
   "name": "0",
   "dtExpiration": "07/14/2011 00:00",
   "quotaList": null,
   "question_array": [
      {
         "question": "0",
         "questionType": "resposta de texto",
         "min": "null",
         "max": "null",
         "responceList": [],
         "answer_array": [
            {
...
```

1.The question is:  will gson.fromJson(json, SuperClass.class) work, as this class has ArrayLists?

I can't see if it works, because I have a problem with date format.  The program throws exception:

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "07/15/2011 00:00"
```

So I had tried to specify format by using:

```
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
```

but result is the same.

2.Can you explain me how to change date format using GsonBuilder?

Thank you

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1.The question is: will gson.fromJson(json, SuperClass.class) work, as this class has ArrayLists?

Yes, provided the `SuperClass` structure matches the JSON structure.

> 2.Can you explain me how to change date format using GsonBuilder?

Use big "M" for month in year.  Small "m" is for minute in hour.

Here's a working example.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm").create();

    SuperClass sc = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), SuperClass.class);
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(sc));
    // {"name":"0","dtExpiration":"07/14/2011 12:00","question_array":[{"question":0,"questionType":"resposta de texto","min":"null","max":"null","responceList":[],"answer_array":[{"id":1,"answer":"yes"},{"id":2,"answer":"no"}]}]}
  }
}

class SuperClass
{
  String name;
  Date dtExpiration;
  List<String> quotaList;
  Question[] question_array;
}

class Question
{
  int question;
  String questionType;
  String min;
  String max;
  List<String> responceList;
  Answer[] answer_array;
}

class Answer
{
  int id;
  String answer;
}
```

Note that on my system, it changed from the 24H clock display to the 12H clock display.

Comment: I had changed it, but getting the same exception! am i doing right: 1st i'm creating Gson object, then setting date format as specified above(with "M" this time) and then trying to convert json?

Comment: thank you very much! I was almost there.. when I was doing Gson gson = new GsonBuilder(), was getting incompatible types error