# Cannot convert yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:SS to date with Gson Retrofit

Tags: android, date, gson

I am using Gson to parse value from response. My response looks like (In postman):

```
{
  "payLoad": {
   "totalItems": 1,
   "totalPages": 1,
   "items": [
    {
      "id": "f13e9f94fbb144d2956326f6c50f4d29",
      "rechargeStatus": "PENDING",
      "dateOfRequest": "2017-05-30T11:29:33",
      "amount": 1,
      "category": "Electricity",
      "operator": "Electricity Limited",
      "whereToRecharge": "212323232"
    }
   ]
  },
  "success": true,
  "timestamp": "2017-05-30T13:08:18"
}
```

When I log my response in `AS`, I have:

```
Fetch Recharge Payload : {totalItems=1.0, totalPages=1.0, items=
[{uuid=f12e9f94fbb144d2956326f6c50f4d29, rechargeStatus=PENDING,
dateOfRequest=2017-05-30T11:29:33, amount=1.0, category=Electricity,
operator=Electricity Limited, whereToRecharge=212323232}]}
```

I have already added `GsonBuilder` for date format as follows (as sugessted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34983454/7014786)):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
            .create();
```

Parsing data looks like:

```
Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) myResponse.payLoad;
List<Recharge> rechargeTable = stringToArray(String.valueOf(map.get("items")), Recharge[].class);

...
public static <T> List<T> stringToArray(String s, Class<T[]> clazz) {
    T[] arr = new Gson().fromJson(s, clazz);
    return Arrays.asList(arr);
}
```

Error I get is:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException:
Unterminated object at line 1 column 94 path $[0].dateOfRequest
```

Main question is to parse date. Do I need to add some more configuration?

Extra Questions:
 - Why my integers are converted to double?
 - Why double quotes are removed from the String values?

Comment: This link might be helpful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473011/retrofit-gson-serialize-date-from-json-string-into-java-util-date

Comment: the json in your logcat doesn't seems good it is malformed json

Comment: @Target Already used the solution implied by that problem.

Comment: @PratikVyas I showed the same request response from `Postman` and the AS. I am using `Logger` from https://github.com/orhanobut/logger. Maybe it just remove something before logging.

Comment: should I show my working example, but it is in a different manner?

Comment: @PratikVyas Yes please do. I get a malformed exception even if I have a space in a String like `category=Electricity Limited`. JSON logged should definitely have those double quotes.

Comment: @ShubhamA. I posted my example try it may help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement this example in your manner.

**Gradle**

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
```

**Interface**

```
public interface ServiceInterface {
@GET(HttpConstants.USERDATAJSON)
    Call<ListData>taskData(@Query("method")String method,@Query("stdID")int stdID);
}
```

**Service Class**

```
public class ServiceClass {
    static ServiceInterface serviceInterface;
//    public static final String baseUrl= HttpConstants.BASE_URL_GEONAME;
    public static final String baseUrl= HttpConstants.baseUrl;

    public static ServiceInterface connection(){
        if(serviceInterface==null){
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Response response=chain.proceed(chain.request());
                    return response;
                }
            });
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .build();
            serviceInterface=retrofit.create(ServiceInterface.class);
        }
        return serviceInterface;
    }
}
```

**The usage**

```
public void getTaskData(){
    ServiceInterface serviceInterface=ServiceClass.connection();
    Call<ListData> call=serviceInterface.taskData("getAllUsersSimple",0);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ListData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ListData> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            Log.v("@@@Response",""+response.toString());
            if(response.isSuccess()){
                listData=response.body();
                dataList=listData.getData();
                printStudentDetails(dataList);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.v("@@@Failure"," Message"+t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

public void printStudentDetails(List<DataPojo> list){
    Log.v("@@@WWe","Student List");
    for (DataPojo dataPojo:list){
        Log.d("Student ID ",dataPojo.getUserId());
        Log.d("Student Name ",dataPojo.getUserName());
        Log.d("Student Age ",dataPojo.getUserAge());
    }
}
```

**Pojo**

```
public class ListData {

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<DataPojo> data = null;
    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private Integer code;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public List<DataPojo> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<DataPojo> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Integer getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}

public class DataPojo {

    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private String userId;
    @SerializedName("user_name")
    @Expose
    private String userName;
    @SerializedName("user_age")
    @Expose
    private String userAge;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserAge() {
        return userAge;
    }

    public void setUserAge(String userAge) {
        this.userAge = userAge;
    }

}
```

**For more references please visit my full example**
https://github.com/pratikvyas1991/NetworkingExample/tree/master/app

Comment: @Shubham A. any progress mate