# Creating Date objects in Kotlin for API level less than or equal to 16

Tags: android, date, datetime, kotlin, timestamp

It may sound very funny and basic, but I am struggling with creating a DateTime kind of object in Kotlin by passing the number of seconds from epoch to it.

Either the examples that I am getting are of the libraries that require API level 26, or just talk about format conversion from string of DD-MM-YYYY to some other.

I have tried "LocalDateTime", "Timestamp", "Date" so far, but Kotlin either refuses to recognise them or the doesn't agree to the function parameters, or is unable to resolve namespace conflict. Or the examples are of Java, which don't work in Kotlin or don't have equivalent in Kotlin.

With Date() I am getting error "Cannot access '': It is private in Date()"

With LocalDate, LocalDateTime, I am getting the API level error

With Timestamp I am getting error "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied". I am passing Long as the parameter as mentioned in documentation. But it is expecting "Parcel" or "Date".

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Calendar for Kotlin

```
val date = Calendar.getInstance()
date.timeInMillis = 5000000
txtDate.text = date.time.toString()
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked! 

Now my struggle is going to be to get Firestore's Timestamp working, which has been giving me headache as well. But that's a different topic I guess.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** In recent versions of Android tooling, *API desugaring* brings to older versions of Android much of the *java.time* functionality that is built into Android 26 and later.

[image]

---

## tl;dr

- Use *java.time* classes.
  Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, or `SimpleDateFormat`.
- Add the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library to your project.
- See [*How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The legacy classes such as `Date` & `Calendar` are *terrible*, created by people who did not understand date-time handling. These classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## *java.time*

The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#ofInstant-java.time.LocalDateTime-java.time.ZoneOffset-java.time.ZoneId-) class replaces the `Date` class, both representing a moment in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

The `Calendar` class, or more precisely, its most commonly-used concrete subclass [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) is replaced by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;  // Capture the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
```

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

## Convert

Best to avoid the legacy date-time classes entirely. But sometimes you may need to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*. In that case, convert. Look to new `to…`/`from…` conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

…and…

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ( ( GregorianCalendar ) calendar ).toZonedDateTime() ;
```

## Back-port

The *java.time* classes are built into Java 8 and later, and Android 26 and later.

For Java 6 & 7, use the back-port found in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Most of the *java.time* functionality is found there. This project is led by the same man leading the *java.time* project and JSR 310, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen).

For Android before 26, use the adaptation of that back-port to Android, the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Instant.fromEpochSeconds(<number>)
```

Comment: ```Instant.fromEpochSeconds(t)``` gives error of unresolved reference.  ```Instant.ofEpochSecond(t)``` gives error of API level