# No time zone indicator into parse Date Json

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a problem with a data type "Date", which I get from a JSON API.

I have an object that contains these two types of Dates.

```
@SerializedName("DateDebut")
public Date dateDebut;

@SerializedName("DateFin")
public Date dateFin;
```

When I post I don't get any errors but on the response.body it goes into catch and I have this error.

Failed to parse date ["2021-05-26T00:00:00"]: No time zone indicator

The type of data I receive is this "DateDebut": "2021-04-21T13: 56: 55.552Z".

I believe it is a DateTime type, while I in my application Date.

```
    @SerializedName("DateDebut")
    public String dateDebutReq;

    @SerializedName("DateFin")
    public String dateFinReq;
    
    public Date dateDebut;
   
    public Date dateFin;
```

If I create two more String types, everything works fine, but I have to leave the Dates for the post.

I would like to avoid having two types 4 elements instead of two.

I have found articles that recommend adding the time zone to the parse in this way

dateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone ("GMT");

but I have the problem with the reception where I do not do any part
Do you have solutions?
Thanks

Comment: Date is an object while you must be getting date as String from the server. You will have to parse that date string to the Date object manually using SImpleDateFormat.

Comment: This might solve your issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473011/retrofit-gson-serialize-date-from-json-string-into-java-util-date#:~:text=Look%20at%20Ondreju's%20response%20to,implement%20this%20in%20retrofit%202.&text=Quite%20literally%20if%20you%20already,ss'Z'%22).

Comment: @NRUSINGHAMOHARANA thanks, I solved the problem with your answer/link